# How do I make my text straight in custom_radio_grouped_button package on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do I make my text straight in custom_radio_grouped_button package on flutter? I tried to make my fontsize smaller but the text is like wrapping because there is not enough space.

[image]

package: https://pub.dev/packages/custom_radio_grouped_button#-readme-tab-

```
  Widget _selectDayBar() {
    return CustomCheckBoxGroup(
      buttonColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
      buttonLables: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
      buttonValuesList: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
      checkBoxButtonValues: (values) => print(values),
      defaultSelected: "Mon",
      horizontal: false,
      hight: 50,
      width: 45,
      selectedColor: Theme.of(context).buttonColor,
      padding: 10,
      customShape: CircleBorder(
        // borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
        side: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).buttonColor)
      ),
      enableShape: true,
      fontSize: 10,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set bigger `width` of `CustomCheckBoxGroup`